# Swift ARM build that will run on Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, swift

I've been fiddling around in my free time trying to get Swift 4.something to run on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with Raspbian Stretch. I found a repo on GitHub which looked promising, but after building it overnight, I discovered the maintainer of the repo left something out of the script and it blew up.

I've also downloaded a pre-compiled version (4.1.2), but the instructions I've found are incomplete. It untarring the file leaves a `/usr/` directory in my download folder, but I can't find instructions on what to do with that directory.

I'm presently using Raspbian Stretch for the operating system. I've tried installing Ubuntu, but I get the lightning bolt of death when I boot up. Ubuntu is not an option for Raspberry Pi 3 B+, according to Ubuntu's website.

Does anyone out there have a set of instructions for installing Swift (4.whateverIsAvailable) on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ that assumes the person reading the instructions eats paste and crayons?

Comment: I'm having to take a bit of a guess which swift you're talking about and what files you found. Have you tried downloading it right from the swift project? https://swift.org/download/#releases The Ubuntu release is possibly your best bet, but we don't know what OS you're running either.

Comment: @T.M. Thank you. That was the first place I looked. LOL. I tried installing Ubuntu on my Pi 3 B+, but I get the lightning bolt of death when I boot. I hooked up a multimeter up to my Pi and checked voltage and I'm getting enough.

Comment: So what OS are you using? Even if you're using Raspbian, it is Debian based as it Ubuntu, so that Ubuntu release should be your best bet. You're going to have to give a lot more details for anyone to help.

Comment: I'll update the question, as I only added it on the tag. I'm using Raspbian Stretch. I got a few memory cards, so I can etch another one.

Comment: @Adrian - I assume you're using the ARM-compatible version of Ubuntu? [This may shed some light](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi)

Comment: Based on that, I can scratch Ubuntu off the list for the time-being until it's available for 3 B+. I guess I'm looking for an ARM7 compatible version of Swift I can use on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+. Every set of instructions I've found has a show-stopper, but I see people can do it...how?

Comment: Did you try downloading the package from swift.org? What exactly happened?

Comment: The Ubuntu version is not an option because there's no ARM version for Raspberry Pi 3 B+. The Raspberry Pi **3 B+** will not run Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you run Ubuntu on your pi. Files made for Ubuntu can work on Raspbian in some cases. But from finding the Swift code repository, it seems that it fails to build on Arm: https://github.com/apple/swift but you could always clone the git repository and install clang and try to build it.

Comment: @Adrian the prebuilt version you refer to that leaves a /usr directory is meant to be installed with the install command: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/install-invocation.html#install-invocation Updating your question with where you found that version would help too. Sorry I don't have an easy guide for running the install command. man install on your pi gets you the very basic syntax too.

Comment: @T.M. I got it working with Raspbian Stretch! See updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got a Raspberry Pi 3 B+, there are several options for getting Swift to install on your Pi.

## Option 1: Raspbian Stretch

[buildSwiftOnARM repo on GitHub](https://github.com/uraimo/buildSwiftOnARM) has a link to a pre-compiled binary.

1. Download it from the link on buildSwiftOnARM.
2. The file will land in `/home/pi/Downloads/`
3. Untar the file with the following command:
   `tar zxvf swift-4.1.3-RPi23-RaspbianStretch.tgz`
4. Upon completion of Step 3, you should hae a directory called `home/pi/Downloads/usr/` that's got all the Swift files in it.
5. Next, copy the files from that directory with the following command:
   `sudo cp -R /home/pi/Downloads/usr/ /`

At that point, typing `swift --version` should tell you what version you've got installed on your Pi. Unfortunately, I haven't found anything that works for cross compiling Xcode projects created on a Mac to build on an ARM processor, so for now, you're stuck editing on the Pi. I've found the easiest route to go is [Visual Studios Code](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-visual-studio-code/) compiled for ARM processors. This build of `Visual Studios Code` can be called from the command line using `code-oss`. You can add basic autocompletion, linters, etc. as you normally would within Visual Studios Code.

Another option is [Hypriot](https://blog.hypriot.com/downloads/). While this works OK, you can't cross compile on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ as of 12/26/2018, so you're left editing in `vim`.

## Option 2: Hypriot

1. Download Hypriot & unzip it
2. Download & install [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/)
3. Insert a microSD card you don't mind nuking into your Mac.
4. Open Disk Utility

   - format your SD card as *MS-DOS (FAT)* with the scheme *Master Boot Record*
5. Open up Balena Etcher

   - Select the Hypriot image
   - Select your newly nuked & formatted microSD card
   - Etch it
6. Once it's done etching, dismount the drive if it doesn't do so automatically and insert it in your Pi 3 B+
7. Boot up your Raspberry Pi 3 B+
8. Login to your pi. Username is `pirate`, password is `hypriot` **(CHANGE THIS AT SOME POINT)**
9. Setup your WiFi by typing `sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`, which will open `nano`.
10. Here's what got WiFi working in my `wpa_supplicant.conf` file:

    ```
    country=US
    ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
    update_config=1

    network={
        ssid="YOUR NETWORK NAME HERE"
        psk="YOUR PASSWORD HERE"
    }
    ```
11. Ctrl + X to exit `nano`
12. Your WiFi won't work until you reboot. Shutdown the Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with `sudo halt`
13. Wait until the lights stop flashing on your Pi to unplug it,  then unplug and replug it.
14. When you reboot and login, try `sudo ping cnn.com` to verify your WiFi works & Ctrl+C to [stop the pinging](https://youtu.be/DRSWpZiDquk?t=16)

At this point, you've got a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ setup that runs Hypriot. Next, you'll want to mosey on over to [`helje5/dockSwiftOnARM`](https://github.com/helje5/dockSwiftOnARM). There's a bunch of links there for getting it going.

## Install Swift for Docker

1. Type `docker pull helje5/rpi-swift`, which will pull down the latest version of Swift for ARM onto your Pi. It'll take a few minutes to finish and you'll see updates on progress in terminal.
2. Type `docker run --rm  helje5/rpi-swift-dev swift --version`

At this point, you should see this outputted in your terminal:

```
Swift version 4.1.2 (swift-4.1.2-RELEASE)
Target: armv7-unknown-linnux-gnueabihf
```

3. [Celebrate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N0OHdRFcJA)

## Creating a project

Here's a [link for cross compiling a Swift project using Docker](https://github.com/AlwaysRightInstitute/swift-mac2arm-x-compile-toolchain)